# Out of memory when opening images using Stream

Tags: vb.net, image, stream, out-of-memory

I hope you can help with what is probably a naive use of Streams in VB.net.

I have a program that batch processes images and am running out of memory making repeated use (in a loop) of the following:

```
Using str As Stream = File.OpenRead(file_stem + CStr(file_number) + "." + file_extension)
    temp_img = Image.FromStream(str)
    str.Close()
End Using
PictureBox1.Image = temp_img
bm = PictureBox1.Image.Clone
```

temp_img is globally declared `Dim temp_img As Image`. bm is declared in the same Sub routine as the loop `Dim bm As Bitmap`.

As the program runs I can see in Task Manager the memory usage rising and then it crashes with an out of memory error. It's as if each time I am using the Stream it is keeping the memory used. What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT:**
This thread appears to have gone cold now, but I thought I would share my "work around" for this. It would seem that this is a VB.net bug as the way I have fixed it is to add a MsgBox which is shown only one, immediately prior to the first call to the subroutine that processes sets of 60 images. I ran a single job that processed 96 sets of 60 images and the memory usage didn't rise above about 45MB. The important thing that makes me think it is a bug is that I only show the MsgBox before the first set of 60 and all are run in series. Showing an MsgBox shouldn't fix anything in itself anyway!

Comment: As a note, each image is a 705KB TIFF and on the current state of my machine it crashes after processing about 480 of them and with the program using about 1GB. 480 x 705KB is about 0.3GB

Comment: When done running a smaller batch, the memory usage rises during processing but then goes back down to something sensible when the batch is done.I tried moving the code into a separate Sub from the loop but that didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Try setting the PictureBox1.Image = Nothing after each loop. If I remember right, the PictureBox has a known issue with releasing images. You might even have to release the PictureBox1 and recreate it.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I just tried that, and temp_img = Nothing, and it doesn't fix it. What is strange is that the memory usage drops back to about 20MB when the processing batch is finished. The batch is broken into chunks of 60 which are handled by a call to a subroutine which contains the loop above.

Comment: You can't trust the memory usage you see in the task manager because of a feature in .Net called Garbage Collection. It will make it look like you are using more and more memory until some point in time when .Net decides to clean up memory. The only indicator you have is if you actually get an Out-Of-Memory error. Are you still getting the error after making the change above?

Comment: Sorry Steve I missed this. I do get the Out-Of-Memory error without the single MsgBox, but not with it.